# Xamarin.Forms DependencyService always returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Hej,

im trying to load some data from the native iOS project using the Dependency Service.

Its a simple task im trying to desirialize some Data that i had saved before, but regardless what i do it **always** returns null.

If i check the values with the debugger in iOS project theyre never null.
Very strange maybe im missing something ...

My Interface Implementation:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SaveRead))]
namespace LindeXF.iOS {
 public class SaveRead : ISaveRead {

        public async Task<ApplicationModel> LoadApplicationModel(string userName) {
            try {

                var userPath = CreatePathJson(userName);

                if (File.Exists(userPath)) {
                    await Task.Run(() => {
                        using (var file = File.OpenText(userPath)) {
                            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                            var m = (ApplicationModel) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(ApplicationModel));

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(ex, "LoadApplicationModel()");
            }

            return new ApplicationModel {Username = userName};
        }
    }
```

in the Portable Project

```
DependencyService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISaveRead>();
var s = await ApplicationModel.DependencyService.LoadApplication(userName);
```

thanks for your Time.

Answer (score 0):

First you deserialize the file contents and store the ApplicationModel object in `m`.

```
using (var file = File.OpenText(userPath)) {
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var m = (ApplicationModel) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(ApplicationModel));
}
```

That looks all good but instead of returning `m`, you create a new ApplicationModel object and return that.

```
return new ApplicationModel {Username = userName};
```

I think you should return `m` like this (for example):

```
using (var file = File.OpenText(userPath)) {
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var m = (ApplicationModel) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(ApplicationModel));
    m.Username = userName;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yout time but i already fixed this the prblems remains

Answer (score -1):

One doubt you are calling method `LoadApplication` from dependency service.

```
var s = await ApplicationModel.DependencyService.LoadApplication(userName);
```

and method declaration is `LoadApplicationModel`.

```
public async Task<ApplicationModel> LoadApplicationModel(string userName) {
}
```

maybe that's the problem? Try using below code for call:

```
var data = await DependencyService.Get<ISaveRead>()
        .LoadApplicationModel(userName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its my fault i copied the wrong Function into stackoverflow. Im calling like that :) Im calling it right ive checked everything 100 times :)

Comment: ahhh okay ...i think its coz of the await task you are running inside ...you are debugging using breakpoints ? . if yes then you are getting the value coz you are giving the time delay for task to complete ..